# svn merging 2 separate branches

Tags: svn, merge

This is the problem. We have a project. The project started in one SVN Repo let's say http://svn1/prj

The project has the standard structure, branches, tags, trunk. Now, we had to give some work to someone else that didn't had acces in out network. So, we have installed another svn instante on a server outside our network. We have done svnadmin dump and svnadmin load into the new repository and gave them access in branch. So now we have http://svn2/prj

Now we want to integrate the branch from svn2 into the trunk of svn1. So we have studied some posibilities but appears we are getting noware. So, the things we have tryied:

- dumping svn2 and importing it over svn1 : svnadmin dump, asvn admin load
- we tyied to do some sort of vendor branch doing svnadmin import of a local copy from svn2. When we did svn merge with this branch and trunk, nothing happened
- we tryied to create another svn on our machine, export the svn2 repo and import it on our svn3 repo. Not good.
- we have tryied to use svn:externals, linked a directory in our branch to the branch in sv2 then do a svn merge. Is not ok.

So we have no more options. We are now looking at git to see if git can help us more with our problem, and to port our project on git, after the merge is ok.

Thx.

Comment: My first thought was "with a developer working offline / out-of-network, Git would be good for this!" ... then I read to the bottom and you said you are evaluating Git.  Good move :)  I've been using Svn for the last 3 years at my job, and almost every month we end up with merge nightmares.

Comment: So, using git you have resolved this problems?

Comment: Well, it might not be an exact fit for your situation with Git, but one of its features is that you could have cloned the repo to a development machine once while connected to your network, then that machine could be taken offline and still be able to branch and commit, then when ready to merge, the development machine could temporarily be re-attached to the network, and the commits merged. It works well for the case where you have a remote or contract developer that comes in maybe once a month, and can sync their commits while in the office.

Comment: Sorry adding a 2nd comment to extend the above because I ran out of space...with Git you could continue to have clones of the same repo on an internal server ("svn1" in your example) and an external clone of it ("svn2") and an outside developer could commit to that external facing repo, then later someone could pull commits from the external repo to the internal one.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like [this](http://linuxwisdom.blogspot.com/2007/08/import-repository-into-another.html)?

Once you get both projects into the same SVN repository, you can merge them using `svn merge --ignore-ancestry`, since they won't share a common parent revision.

Comment: We tried this. We created a dorectory in our branch repository and imported the dump into it. Nothing happened. Nothing was imported.

Comment: Maybe i didn't understand you right. So, i import my dump file into a directory of my repository, let's say branches and then do a merge. If this is it, we have tried this and didn't worked as expected.

Comment: Which one was it? Nothing was imported, or your merge didn't work?